# Best way to deploy and access private pod deployed on OCI Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, opensearch, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Im new to OCI and k8s so im looking for information here.
So i have used OKE on OCI to quick create a k8s cluster with default settings, and used the cloud shell to deploy OpeanSearch and OpenSearch Dashboard in it. I was able to expose the OS Dashboard pod with the LoadBalancer, but as i understand anyone can access it that way. As im dealing with sensitive data i need to make it private somehow.
Now what I need is a way to deploy the OpenSearch in an OCI k8s privately so i can ingest data in to it and few select people can access the Dashboards GUI, what would be some solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many solutions to this problem.

Keep the cluster nodes in the private subnet and loadbalancer in public subnet. Add ingress rules to the security list attached to the subnets of both lb and nodes. Hardcode the source ip addresses in the ingress to the loadbalancer to the list of ips to which you want to give access. The ingress to the nodes should only be from the loadbalancer subnet cidr.

Comment: Thank you for the replay, thats what I ended up doing. 
Any idea on how i would ingest data it to mentioned OpenSearch instance?